# How to use pip for python 3.9 instead of inbuilt python 3.8 in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-20.04

Today I faced a problem regarding pip3 in Ubuntu. Ubuntu comes with python 3.8 but I wanted to use latest versions of python, like 3.9 or maybe 3.10. So I installed it using 'ppa:deadsnakes' repository and also installed pip. But the problem is I want to use pip in python 3.9 instead of version 3.8. So I changed the default python version to 3.9 and everything crashed.
So reverted to python 3.8. Whenever I install some package it gets installed using python 3.8.
Help me, how can I use python 3.9 pip and install packages in python 3.9 without changing the default version.
Any help is appreciated.

--> Thing I want is that when I want to install python package using
`pip3 install <package_name>` it must install in python3.9 and not in python3.8

Comment: make sure your interpreter is the correct one.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to install pip separately

You should be able to refer to it as such

`python3.9 -m pip install`

Comment: Yes there is pip shipped with python but in Ubuntu we have to explicitly install pip using ```sudo apt install python3-pip```.

Comment: I only ever use pip through this method. I never run bare pip.

Comment: @Satvir All Python3 distributions since 3.4 come with their own Python. That's not unique to Ubuntu. Does this answer solve your problem?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I cannot use pip using the command mentioned without installing the pip explicitly in Ubuntu. If I install explicitly than it is working.

Comment: why is this the case for Ubutu? This solution worked, but I typically am used to using pip3, or finding where python3 is installed and specifying the full path to pip at worst case scenario

Comment: @dataviews pip comes installed with Python3.4+, however its binary / symlink can get overridden due to poor management of Python environments or PATH changes. Therefore it's suggested to always use `python -m pip` to verify that you're actually installing packages into the correct python environment (on any OS)

Answer (score 4):

Hello everyone I fixed my issue.
The problem is we cannot override default python version in Ubuntu as so many things depend on it.
So I just made an alias as : `alias pip3='python3.9 -m pip'` and alias for python : `alias python3='/usr/bin/python3.9'`

If anyone face this issue please do what I specify and you will be good to go.
Now all my packages are being installed in python3.9.

Answer (score 2):

Currently all python3 versions are using the same pip version which can be installed by:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

The easiest way to work with a specific python version is creating a virtualenv and working under it. When working with a virtualenv you can use pip freely without worrying about which python version it belongs.

Answer (score -1):

you can use pip for python3.9 by `pip3.9 install <package-name>`

Comment: There is no such thing like you have mentioned above. Only ```pip3 install <package_name>``` works in Ubuntu.

Comment: That would depend on how/where Python gets installed from. Some packages do include `pipX.Y` binaries. Otherwise, add to your bashrc `alias pip3.9='python3.9 -m pip'` @SatvirSingh